# Optimize CTE RECURSIVE QUERY in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a database and am trying to find the best way to pass a user ID and have it show that user plus any records of subordinates.  I'm using the idea at "How to run Hierarchical Queries with PostgreSQL" from https://www.highgo.ca/2021/04/09/how-to-run-hierarchical-queries-with-postgresql/ as that's the basic setup we want, and have added a table on top of it, but I'm not sure if the way I have implemented the CTE RECURSIVE query into the SELECT from the table is the best.

How would I go about making this better and testing it?

Fiddle with Current Structure and SQL:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w7EdwJ1tonLeoe7hc4tKnP/0

EDIT:
I get the expected results, so user ID 7782 sees their records plus their subordinates, as shown below with the Query, Results, and EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

I *think* it is as good as it gets but am not sure as I'm new to RECURSIVE queries like this.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id, last_name, assign_to, emp.empno, emp.ename
FROM datatables_demo dd
LEFT JOIN emp ON dd.assign_to = emp.empno
WHERE 1=1 

AND ((assign_type = 'global') OR (assign_type = 'user' AND assign_to IN(

    WITH RECURSIVE cte_query AS (
        SELECT empno FROM emp WHERE empno = 7782
        UNION ALL
        SELECT e.empno FROM emp e JOIN cte_query C ON C.empno = e.mgr
    ) SELECT empno FROM cte_query

)))

ORDER BY last_name, empno, id;
```

| id | last_name | assign_to | empno | ename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 47 | Baldwin |  |  |  |
| 22 | Berry | 7782 | 7782 | CLARK |
| 46 | Camacho |  |  |  |
| 7 | Chandler | 7782 | 7782 | CLARK |
| 15 | Fitzpatrick | 1 | 1 | BRADSHAW |
| 48 | Frank |  |  |  |
| 29 | Green | 7934 | 7934 | PARKER |
| 37 | Hatfield | 7782 | 7782 | CLARK |
| 30 | Itou | 1 | 1 | BRADSHAW |
| 14 | Kennedy | 7934 | 7934 | PARKER |
| 45 | Walton | 1 | 1 | BRADSHAW |
| 44 | Yamamoto | 7934 | 7934 | PARKER |

---

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE**

```
Sort  (cost=29.06..29.14 rows=30 width=25) (actual time=0.137..0.139 rows=12 loops=1)
  Sort Key: dd.last_name, emp.empno, dd.id
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=25.23..28.33 rows=30 width=25) (actual time=0.106..0.119 rows=12 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (dd.assign_to = emp.empno)
        ->  Seq Scan on datatables_demo dd  (cost=23.89..26.89 rows=30 width=15) (actual time=0.076..0.088 rows=12 loops=1)
              Filter: (((assign_type)::text = 'global'::text) OR (((assign_type)::text = 'user'::text) AND (hashed SubPlan 2)))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 36
              SubPlan 2
                ->  CTE Scan on cte_query  (cost=20.72..23.54 rows=141 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.049 rows=3 loops=1)
                      CTE cte_query
                        ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..20.72 rows=141 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.048 rows=3 loops=1)
                              ->  Seq Scan on emp emp_1  (cost=0.00..1.19 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
                                    Filter: (empno = 7782)
                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 14
                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.33..1.67 rows=14 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=3)
                                    Hash Cond: (e.mgr = c.empno)
                                    ->  Seq Scan on emp e  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=15 loops=3)
                                    ->  Hash  (cost=0.20..0.20 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=3)
                                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                          ->  WorkTable Scan on cte_query c  (cost=0.00..0.20 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=3)
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.15..1.15 rows=15 width=10) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=15 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              ->  Seq Scan on emp  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=15 width=10) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=15 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.265 ms
Execution Time: 0.169 ms
```

Comment: Please post the expected result you are looking for, as text - **no images**. If the fiddle is producing correct results then post the result of `explain analyze select ...`, also as text and making sure to maintain indentation. Capture the explain results and past then into you question between lines containing only **```**.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and clarifying. I have appended that information to the question under an EDIT.